# How to retrieve the key values of a nested data set in D3

Tags: d3.js, obiee

I am trying to add D3 visualizations to OBIEE and the first graph I need to accomplish is a multi-series line graph. The data is directly obtained from an OBIEE narrative view in this format:

```
var data = [ ];

data.push({category:"Cat1",date:"20130101",suma:9.11});
data.push({category:"Cat2",date:"20130101",suma:2.66});
data.push({category:"Cat3",date:"20130101",suma:18.00});
data.push({category:"Cat4",date:"20130101",suma:32.49});
data.push({category:"Cat5",date:"20130101",suma:37.74});
```

There are 155 lines like those, for different dates ranging from 2013 to 2015. To separate them by categories, so I can then assign one line and color to each category, I nest the data in this way:

```
var dataGroup = d3.nest() 
.key(function(d) {return d.category;}) 
.entries(data);
```

The variable dataGroup is then an array of 5 objects that looks like this:

```
0: Object
key: "Cat1"
values: Array[31]
    0: Object
       category: "Cat1"
       date: "20130101"
       suma: 9.11
       __proto__: Object
   ... 
   1: Object
   key: "Cat2"
   values: Array[31]
       0: Object
       category: "Cat2"
       date: "20130101"
       suma: 2.66
       __proto__: Object
   ... ...
```

What I am trying to do next is to assign the colors for the categories.

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
color.domain(d3.keys(dataGroup).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));
```

And here is where I am having trouble. The result of this filter function is:

```
Array[5]
0: "0"
1: "1"
2: "2"
3: "3"
4: "4"
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Instead of what I think I need that is:

```
Array[5]
0: "Cat1"
1: "Cat2"
2: "Cat3"
3: "Cat4"
4: "Cat5"
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I have tried several approaches and none of them have worked. At this point I am about to give up on adding D3 to OBIEE, although I really wanted to achieve it, but I am struggling to understand this and I seem to be totally unable. Perhaps I should be learning Javascript first of perhaps all the mind bending that D3 seems to require to understand the data management is too much for me.

I would really appreciate any help on this. I am sorry if I made any mistakes in submitting the question, I tried to format it correctly, but this is the first time I post anything here.

Thank you very much and best regards,
Ana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keys()` method (not when used as part of `nest()`) is intended for standard associative arrays, not nested data. You should take the `values` of `dataGroup` and iterate through each to extract the `category` property. There may be additional problems in your code, but try

```
color.domain(d3.values(dataGroup).map(function(d) {
    return d.category; 
}).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));
```

to start

Comment: No, OP needs `d3.values(dataGroup).map(function(d) { return d.category; })`.

Comment: And then the "date" filter shouldn't even be necessary as this value doesn't appear as a category :)

Comment: probably true, but since the OP had the filter in to start with, I'm assuming he anticipates it might be necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand better how to retrieve the keys of my data. The results I am getting now are a bit more encouraging.