# How to retrieve nested values in a JSON file using D3/JS?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am struggling to find a way to call data from a json URL due to the way it is nested, shown below.

```
[
{"data":
  "Aatrox":
    "id": "Aatrox"
    "hp": "500"
   "Ashe":
     "id": "Ashe"
     "hp": "350"
}]
```

I am trying to use the 'hp' value as the height data point for a bar graph using d3.js, and using the 'id' value as a label under each bar, but I'm unsure how to call upon the data and store it in variables that I can use in my d3 code.

```
d3.json("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.7.16/data/em_us/champion.json
", function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

Currently I'm just logging the data in the console because I'm not sure how to store the specific parts of it that I want in a variable.

[How to retrieve the key values of a nested data set in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428131/how-to-retrieve-the-key-values-of-a-nested-data-set-in-d3)

This question helped me a little bit as a starting point but I'm still not totally sure how to proceed.

The main issue I am having is the file structure of the JSON is a bit strange and I'm not sure what 'x' would be in the case that I wanted to pull just 'hp' in:

data.'x'.stats.hp

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: There's no way to make that JSON work? What makes it invalid?

Comment: @Hawke your JSON is not invalid.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado the data in the URL provided is valid but not the data sample included in the question.

Comment: Yes, @sparta93, I'm seeing that frustrated attempt to reproduce the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D3, the `data()` function accepts three things:

1. An array
2. A function
3. Nothing

Right now, your JSON contains just a bunch of nested objects:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {...
        },
        "Ahri": {...
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, the first step is converting this into an array of objects, which we can use to bind data. There are several ways for doing that, this one being easy for a beginner:

```
var data = [];
var obj = json.data;
for (var key in obj) {
    data.push(obj[key])
}
```

Now that we have an array of objects (named `data`), like this...

```
[{
    id: "Aatrox"
}, {
    id: "Ahri"
}]
```

... we can get the `hp` property:

```
.attr('width', function(d) {
    return scale(d.stats.hp)
})
```

Here is a working demo using your code and changing the data array only:

```js
  var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 500)
    .attr('height', 500)

  d3.json("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.7.16/data/en_US/champion.json", function(json) {
    var data = [];
    var obj = json.data;
    for (var key in obj) {
      data.push(obj[key])
    }

    var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.stats.hp
      })])
      .range([0, 500]);

    canvas.selectAll('rect')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return scale(d.stats.hp)
      })
      .attr('height', 6)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 7
      })
      .attr('fill', 'blue')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use like this.

```
d3.json("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.7.16/data/em_us/champion.json
", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg');
    canvas.selectAll('rect')
        .data(Object.values(data.data))
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            return d.stats.hp;
        });

    canvas.selectAll('text')
        .data(Object.values(data.data))
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.id
        });
});
```